# Chef solo with berkshelf: cookbook not resolved

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, berkshelf

I've created this `Vagrantfile`'s provioner section:

```
config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    chef.add_recipe "wildfly"
end
```

I'm getting this error:

```
==> default: Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
==> default:
==> default: Missing Cookbooks:
==> default: ------------------
==> default: No such cookbook: wildfly
```

So, I've created a `Berksfile` and a `metadata.rb` files:

`Berksfile`:

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'
metadata
```

`metadata.rb`:

```
name 'webapi'
maintainer 'The Authors'
maintainer_email 'you@example.com'
license 'all_rights'
description 'Installs/Configures webapi'
long_description 'Installs/Configures webapi'
version '0.1.0'

depends 'java_se', '~> 9.0.1'
depends 'wildfly', '~> 0.4.0'
```

So, then I've performed `berks install` command. The first issue I've detected is that I don't quite detect where `berks` has placed cookbooks. It seems that it works right, nevertheless, I don't find where cookbooks dependencies are located, I mean, a `.\cookbooks` folder is not created after performing `berks install` command.

```
Resolving cookbook dependencies...
Fetching 'olingo' from source at .
Fetching cookbook index from https://supermarket.chef.io...
Using apt (6.1.4)
Using homebrew (4.2.0)
Using java (1.50.0)
Using java_se (9.0.1)
Using ohai (5.2.0)
Using olingo (0.1.0) from source at .
Using wildfly (0.4.0)
Using yum (5.1.0)
Using windows (3.4.0)
```

Regardless of that, I've performed `vagrant provision` again, and `wildfly` cookbook is not resolved:

```
The cookbook path 'D:/projects/swiller/querydsl/olingo/infrastructure/cookbooks' doesn't exist. Ignoring...
Running provisioner: chef_solo...
==> default: Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
==> default:
==> default: Missing Cookbooks:
==> default: ------------------
==> default: No such cookbook: wildfly
```

Answer (score 2):

You either need to use the `vagrant-berkshelf` plugin, or use the `berks vendor` command to write all the cookbooks to a folder and then point Vagrant at that (which is what the plugin does internally). `berks install` only downloads them to your workstation, it doesn't put the cookbooks in a place/format that anything other than Berkshelf understands.